# What is PayBee and how is it related to Monero?

Tags: globee, payment-integration

What is [PayBee](https://payb.ee/) and how is it related to Monero?

Is it being worked on is a private repository? I cannot see much recent activity in [GitHub](https://github.com/paybee) other than forking code from BitPay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is PayBee and how is it related to Monero?

PayBee is a BitPay like payment processor. It will use Monero and Bitcoin as "default" currencies as far as I know. Fluffypony explanation of "what is Paybee" is as follows:

> It's a payment gateway I've been developing along with a few partners. We had to deal with a few false starts and issues along the way, but it's (finally) getting close-ish to release.

**Source:** https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/40gkul/what_is_paybee_does_it_have_something_to_do_with/

---

> Is it being worked on is a private repository?

As far as I know, yes. In addition, it has been in private beta for a few months now and merchants were, and are still, able to sign up to participate in it.

Comment: Is the website http://www.paybee.org related in any way?

Comment: The official website is payb.ee as far as I know.

Comment: it's becoming globee.com