# Which currencies will be supported by GloBee?

Tags: payment-integration, fiat, globee

Besides Monero which currencies are currently supported by [GloBee](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-is-paybee-and-how-is-it-related-to-monero)?

In addition to cryptocurrency acceptance does GloBee allow merchants to convert payments into fiat, like BitPay? If conversion are possible, which fiat currencies are supported?

Since PayBee is still in private beta, please specify if you know the answer will change after public launch.

Comment: I know its too late, but still you can refer this [url](https://www.cryptonewsz.com/globee-allows-merchants-to-accept-cryptocurrencies-safely/18037/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GloBee is out from beta. Check http://globee.com website

GloBee will support Monero, Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Litecoin, Dogecoin and Decred cryptocurrency payments. Merchant settlements will be handled in any combination of Monero, Bitcoin and fiat currency

Answer (score 2):

GloBee supports Monero, Bitcoin Lightning, Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Ethereum, Litecoin, Decred, Dogecoin & Ripple:)

GloBee also allows fiat conversion, reach out to them on info@globee.com.