# How do I install the Monero GUI on PureOS?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

Now that [Purism accepts Monero payments](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/747w6h/purism_can_accept_monero/) through [globee](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-is-paybee-and-how-is-it-related-to-monero) I am interested in using Monero on a [Librem laptop](https://puri.sm/products/) which runs PureOS.

What are the installation steps (including necessary dependencies) required to install the official Monero GUI on [PureOS](https://pureos.net/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PureOS is based on Debian so you need to work with the Ubuntu x64 instructions on [the project page](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui) and adapt them slightly. Main differences:

- you need `git` to download the project
- `libqt5qml-graphicaleffects` is an Ubuntu package and is named `qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects` in the Debian world
- you need the `libreadline-dev` and `qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel` packages

#### Steps to install monero-gui on PureOS

This has been tested with PureOS 8.0 "Prometheus" Beta 1.

- Open a terminal
- Download dependencies

  (This assumes that you have sudo and that your user is a sudoer)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libzmq3-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qttools5-dev-tools qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects libreadline-dev qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
  ```
- Download and build the project

  ```
  cd ~
  mkdir monero
  cd monero
  git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui
  cd monero-gui
  ./build.sh
  ```
- Go and get a cuppa while the project gets compiled...
- Run the GUI:

  ```
  cd ~/monero/monero-gui/build/release/bin
  ./monero-wallet-gui
  ```

Answer (score 3):

PureOS is based on Debian, so you can follow the instructions on this page (follow the Ubuntu and Mint path):

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui

1. Install Monero dependencies
   For Ubuntu and Mint

`sudo apt install build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libzmq3-dev`

2. Grab an up-to-date copy of the monero-gui repository

`git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui.git`

3. Go into the repository

`cd monero-gui`

4. Install the GUI Dependencies

For Ubuntu 16.04+ x64

`sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qttools5-dev-tools qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qt-labs-settings libqt5qml-graphicaleffects`

Optional : To build the flag `WITH_SCANNER`

For Ubuntu and Mint

`sudo apt install qtmultimedia5-dev qml-module-qtmultimedia libzbar-dev`

5. Build the GUI

For Ubuntu and Mint

`./build.sh`

The executable can be found in the `build/release/bin` folder.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include these steps here please?

Comment: Note that some of the libs don't exist as PureOS packages so you need to adapt the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The Monero-gui is now available through Whonix's APT repository. For easier instructions, see this question here: [How to install Monero on Debian Linux?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/how-to-install-monero-on-debian-linux/12151#12151)